# Remote RPC client disassociated while doing operation on datasets with persisted datasets

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

While performing join or any operation with persisted datasets with other non-persisted datasets, Spark server throws ***Remote RPC client disassociated***. Following is piece of code that causing issue.

```
Dataset<Row> dsTableA = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").options(dbConfig)
.option("dbTable", "SELECT * FROM tableA").load().persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER());
Dataset<Row> dsTableB = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").options(dbConfig)
.option("dbTable", "SELECT * FROM tableB").load().persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER());

Dataset<Row> anotherTableA = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").options(dbConfig)
.option("dbTable", "SELECT * FROM tableC").load();
anotherTableA.write().format("json").save("/path/toJsonA"); // Working Fine - No use of persisted datasets

Dataset<Row> anotherTableB = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").options(dbConfig)
.option("dbTable", "SELECT * FROM tableD").load();
dsTableA.createOrReplaceTempView("dsTableA");
dsTableB.createOrReplaceTempView("dsTableB");
anotherTableB.createOrReplaceTempView("anotherTableB");

Dataset<Row> joinedTable = sparkSession.sql("select atb.* from anotherTableB atb INNER JOIN dsTableA dsta ON atb.pid=dsta.pid LEFT JOIN dsTableB dstb ON atb.ssid=dstb.ssid");
joinedTable.write().format("json").save("/path/toJsonB"); 
// ERROR : Remote RPC client disassociated 
// Working fine if Datasets dsTableA and dsTableB were not persisted
```

Part of logs

```
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 17.0 (TID 111, X.X.X.X, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5342 bytes)
INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Launching task 111 on executor id: 0 hostname: X.X.X.X.
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_13_piece0 in memory on X.X.X.X:37153 (size: 12.9 KB, free: X.2 GB)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_12_piece0 in memory on X.X.X.X:37153 (size: 52.0 KB, free: X.2 GB)
ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 0 on X.X.X.X: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-12121212121211-0000/0 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 134)
WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 17.0 (TID 111, X.X.X.X): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 0 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-12121212121211-0000/0 removed: Command exited with code 134
INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 0 (epoch 8)
```

If Datasets dsTableA and dsTableB were not persisted, then everything works smoothly. But must have to use persisted datasets. So how to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you attach the remote logs (using "yarn logs" to retrieve it)?

Comment: @waltersu I am not using YARN, this is just standalone environment